# Android Facebook sdk Session.OpenRequest(myFragment) is undefined?

Tags: java, android, facebook, session, sdk

For some reason I cannot see the line of code:

```
session = new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallBack(statusCallBack)
```

It gives me an error that `Session.OpenRequest(myFragment)` is undefined. Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what i was doing wrong. It has to be a fragment from the support library. I was extending the regular fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `Session.OpenRequest(Fragment fragment)` constructor should work. Assuming that you have added Facebook SDK properly in your project, organize the imports in your class to import the `Session.OpenRequest` class. This constructor seems to be invisible for your code.

If you are using Eclipse IDE organize imports by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O`.

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason. I removed and added the facebook sdk again and organized the imports. Tried to import session.openrequest class directly but still nothing